# Magento 2.3.3 Hide product that are missing product image

Tags: magento2, products

Im using Magento2  v2.3.3 Open source.

My store consist of around 76000 products and some of them are missing product images. Is it possible without much coding to hide products on the frontend that doesn't have product images?

I have already looked at these but It didn't do much for me:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14244485/hide-products-without-images-magento
- https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/How-can-i-hide-products-with-no-images-on-frontend/td-p/115508
- https://www.commercers.com/blog/en/magento-products-not-Hide-without-artikelbild/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way and cheapest (in number code lines) is to create a custom cronjob that verifies whether products have images and if not, it disables them.

This will cause exclusion from the sitemap.xml, 404 on PDP access and exclusion from any category listing or search results (as the product's associated document(s) in Elasticsearch will be removed).

Comment: May I ask why using cronjob? I mean this is not a schedule task. Could we just write a script to check and set product visibility from the script itself?

Comment: yes, of course you can write a script to check and set the proper visibility, but i am thinking more of a long term solution. if you have, for example, product imports from a 3rd party entity (erp, pim, etc), then the problem will reoccur, so i was thinking of a cronjob that can be scheduled after such an import and deal with the problem :)

Comment: How would I set up a cronjob like this? :)

Comment: Check this article https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cron/custom-cron-tut.html you will have to create a custom cron in Magento and in its `execute()` method call another model that collects the list of products which have no images and disables them.